# SQL 2 same rows

Tags: sql

My query:

```
SELECT CONCAT(f.name, ' ', f.parent_names) AS FullName,
       stts.name AS 'Status',
       u.name AS Unit,
       city.name AS City,
       hus.mobile1 AS HusbandPhone,
       wife.mobile1 AS WifePhone,
       f.phone AS HomePhone,
       f.contact_initiation_date AS InitDate,
       fh.created_at AS StatusChangeDate,
       cmt.created_at AS CommentDate,
       cmt.comment AS LastComment
FROM families f
JOIN categories stts ON f.family_status_cat_id = stts.id
JOIN units u ON f.unit_id = u.id
JOIN categories city ON f.main_city_cat_id = city.id
JOIN contacts hus ON f.husband_id = hus.id
JOIN contacts wife ON f.wife_id = wife.id
JOIN comments cmt ON f.id = cmt.commentable_id
AND cmt.created_at =
    (SELECT MAX(created_at)
     FROM comments
     WHERE commentable_id = f.id)
JOIN family_histories fh ON f.id = fh.family_id
AND fh.created_at =
    (SELECT MAX(created_at)
     FROM family_histories
     WHERE family_id = f.id
         AND family_history_cat_id = 1422)
WHERE f.id = 17883
```

Question: the result is 2 rows - but they are the same. Why do I get 2 results and not only one?

Comment: This depends on your tables' structures and the data in your tables. Can you add a description of the relevant tables structures to your question?

Comment: That is due to JOIN. Use `DISTINCT` keyword to get distinct rows.

Comment: Which of the IDs used in JOINs are **guaranteed** (not just supposed) to be **unique**?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably there is a double relation on comments or family_histories, you can check it out by returning `*` as result. There should be a distinction somewhere.

Supply the complete result to find the problem.

You *could* (but not recommended) solve it by setting `DISTINCT`.

```
SELECT DISTINCT CONCAT(f.name, ' ', f.parent_names) AS FullName, stts.name AS 'Status', u.name AS Unit, city.name AS City, hus.mobile1 AS HusbandPhone, wife.mobile1 AS WifePhone, f.phone AS HomePhone, f.contact_initiation_date AS InitDate, fh.created_at AS StatusChangeDate, cmt.created_at AS CommentDate, cmt.comment AS LastComment
FROM families f JOIN categories stts ON f.family_status_cat_id = stts.id
JOIN units u ON f.unit_id = u.id
JOIN categories city ON f.main_city_cat_id = city.id
JOIN contacts hus ON f.husband_id = hus.id
JOIN contacts wife ON f.wife_id = wife.id
JOIN comments cmt ON f.id = cmt.commentable_id AND cmt.created_at = (SELECT MAX(created_at) FROM comments WHERE commentable_id = f.id)
JOIN family_histories fh ON f.id = fh.family_id AND fh.created_at = (SELECT MAX(created_at) FROM family_histories WHERE family_id = f.id AND family_history_cat_id = 1422)
WHERE f.id = 17883
```

Comment: It is my opinion that just using distinct is not a great approach. If there's duplicate data and you can't do anything about that, you don't really have a choice. But if the duplication is happening because you aren't filtering correctly, using distinct just hides an error that may have undesirable future consequences.

Answer (score 1):

When you join tables where there is a one-to-many relationship you will appear to get multiple rows returned, when in fact the row only exists once in the master table, but there are multiple rows of related data in one of the child tables.

Also be aware that data you expect could be missing because there is no matching records in the child tables, in that case use a [LEFT JOIN](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join_left.asp).